# Submit WordPress comment form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, form-submit

I'm trying to post the default WordPress comment form with jQuery for a functional usage. Following is the simple script, but the form doesn't submit.

Since the default comment form has a common ID as "#commentform"

```
jQuery( ".save-rating" ).click(function() {
    jQuery( "#commentform" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: Your comment form needs to be validated in order to finally submit. Do you have any more code to post or are you running into trouble with a valid submission?

Comment: What exactly needs to be done is; I'm using Multi Rating plugin to get a star rating. I'm Trying to combine it with a WP comment. So, I have placed the rating widget under the form (below the textarea field), hiding the "post comment" button and submit the form on click of "Submit Rating" button. Is this possible?

Comment: Should be possible. I think the hidden submit could be a problem. Does this work when the submit button is still visible? Try visibility: hidden instead of display: none.